# How to use .grid with a scrollbar in a tkinter window?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar

I have a tkinter window with several images that use grid. I tried to grid a scrollbar to the right side of the window but don't know what options to use because "side = right", "fill = Y" cannot be used inside grid. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use `place(relx=1, y=0, relheight=1, anchor='ne')`.

Comment: Or put those images inside a frame, then use `pack()` on the frame and the scrollbar.

Comment: All of the options  for `grid` are documented.

Answer (score 1):

Grid is row / column oriented. So each widget needs its row and column in the geometry manager set. Here is a demo that answers the question posed.

```
# create a widget and scrollbar
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
vs = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=text.yview)
text.configure(yscrollcommand=vs.set)

# set the row, column and expansion for each widget
text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')
vs.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='news')

# now make the grid manager expand to fill the available space in root.
# making 0, 0 expand to use all the spare space and 0,1 be fixed
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

If you are managing a set of images on label widgets then put them in a frame to separate out the geometry management of those. You might want to consider if you should
put them into a canvas instead which has quite good scrolling support.